# How to convert LatLng to (x , y) pixels and vice versa?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps API V3 and I want to create an editable 100px X 100px Rectangle when user clicks on the map.

Now I only need to have (x,y) point that user clicks and then lat and lng of (x+100 , y+100).
Any Idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This function should create a 100 x100 rectangle around the center(LatLng) that you pass to it.

```
function setRectangle(center){
    var scale = Math.pow(2,map.getZoom());
    var proj = map.getProjection();
    var wc = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(center);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var sw = new google.maps.Point(((wc.x * scale) - 50)/ scale, ((wc.y * scale) - 50)/ scale);
    bounds.extend(proj.fromPointToLatLng(sw));
    var ne = new google.maps.Point(((wc.x * scale) + 50)/ scale, ((wc.y * scale) + 50)/ scale);
    bounds.extend(proj.fromPointToLatLng(ne));
    var opts = {
        bounds: bounds,
        map: map,
        editable:true
    }
    var rect = new google.maps.Rectangle(opts);

}
```

Comment: Instead of `Math.pow(2,map.getZoom())` you could also use `1 << map.getZoom()`

Comment: Instead of `((wc.x * scale) - 50)/ scale` you can use `wc.x - 50/scale`

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {};
overlay.setMap(map);

var proj = overlay.getProjection();
var pos = marker.getPosition();
var p = proj.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(pos);
```

now you can get pixels from p.x and p.y

Comment: Even though this looks very promising, it has a major drawback (as of Google Maps v3.16): the projection, returned by `overlay.getProjection()` gets updated only when the overlay is redrawn. This means that if you pan/zoom the map, you cannot use the projection until the next draw.